# Error in loading property file

Tags: java, properties, property-files

I am getting error while loading property file.
I am getting the following error:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: neosEntitelment.properties (The system cannot

```
find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(FileInputStream.java)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at noes.Entitelment.CreateProperties.<init>(CreateProperties.java:45)
        at noes.Entitelment.NeosDatabase.oracleJdbcConnection(NeosDatabase.java:68)
        at noes.Entitelment.NeosDatabase.getDataByDB(NeosDatabase.java:20)
        at noes.Entitelment.SoapWebService.getEntitelmentDetails(SoapWebService.java:254)
        at noes.Entitelment.Entitelment.doGet(Entitelment.java:27)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Project structure is:

```
Project
    -src
    -neosEntitelment.properties
```

Here is my code

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("neosEntitelment.properties"));
setNeoJdbcConnectionUrl(prop.getProperty("neo.jdbc.connection.url"));
setNeoUserName(prop.getProperty("neo.db.userName"));
setNeoPassword(prop.getProperty("neo.db.password"));
```

Comment: Are you running this in eclipse or any other IDE or through command line?

Comment: try putting it in quotations. `prop.load(new FileInputStream("neosEntitelment.properties"));`

Comment: @Anacron - Yes i am running this on Eclipse with java 1.8

Comment: @kism3t- Tried but not running, same error

Comment: Is the file name spelled correctly? neosEntit**el**ment.properties - should it be "neosEntit**le**ment.properties"? Verify in both the file name and in the java code :)

Comment: @anacron- Name is correctly spelled.(I spelled neosEntitelment in all the places)

Comment: The same code and same file structure is working for me. I got the same error when there was a mismatch in the file name..

Comment: @anacron- What can i say now...... It is still not working for me :(

Comment: When Clean and running tomcat, getting error above in my question

Comment: Hint: log (or print out) `new File(".").getCanonicalPath()` so you can see what your working directory is... then consider that you're trying to load the file relative from there.

Comment: @JonSkeet- getCanonicalPath is  'C:\Users\bs185227\Desktop' But my property file is at 'C:\Users\bs185227\Desktop\NCR\Workspace\Workspace_Neon\NEOEntitelmentData'. Can you suggest what can i do now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest U use "getClass.getResourceAsStream('/neosEntitelment.properties')"

Comment: Thanks for your help, i just used -----  prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File(getClass().getResource("/neosEntitelment.properties").toURI())));    ----- and my problem get resolved.

Comment: Can you suggest, it will also work when i make jar of this and put the property file outside the project???

Comment: Why create a new File and a FileInputStream? getResourceAsStream() already returns a stream. Also, yes, it will work once it's packaged in the jar, as long as you include the file when you're compiling.

Comment: Alvin- I want to put this property file outside my project, so that i can easily made changes whenever required. Then in that case, what changes i have to made...

Answer (score -2):

Put the file "neosEntitelment.properties" into "src" directory.

Comment: Not getting solution by putting the file "neosEntitelment.properties" into "src" directory